# How to check if MOSS Standard or MOSS Enterprise is installed?

Tags: sharepoint, moss

How is it possible to check if MOSS Standard or MOSS Enterprise is installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This link should sort you out...

[Determining sharepoint versions](http://weblogs.asp.net/danlewis/archive/2008/09/06/determine-which-version-of-sharepoint-is-installed.aspx)

Edit: The article has now disappeared, so see Dan's answer below

Comment: What about checking programmatically (not the bitness part, but the MOSS version)?

Answer (score 4):

Since the link given in Paul's answer seems to require sign up at ASP.NET weblogs, here's the answer without having to go away and log in elsewhere:

Central Admin -> Operations -> Upgrade and Migration -> Convert license type

The 'Current License' field will tell you. Once an enterprise license key has been entered, you also need to enable the enterprise features by visiting:

Central Admin -> Operations -> Upgrade and Migration -> Enable Enterprise Features

Once this is done, you can't revert the installation back to standard features.

Comment: Thanks Dan - the article has now disappeared from the site, so I assume thats why its prompting for a login.

Answer (score 2):

From code, an easy way to check MOSS license is to see if the "Premium" (Enterprise) Farm-scoped features are installed in `SPFarm.Local.FeatureDefinitions`:

```
99ee0928-7342-4739-865d-35b61ea4eaf0    BDCAdminUILinks
e4e6a041-bc5b-45cb-beab-885a27079f74    ExcelServer
a573867a-37ca-49dc-86b0-7d033a7ed2c8    PremiumSiteStapling
a10b6aa4-135d-4598-88d1-8d4ff5691d13    ipfsAdminLinks
cdfa39c6-6413-4508-bccf-bf30368472b3    DataConnectionLibraryStapling
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this article on "How to check if SharePoint Standard or SharePoint Enterprise is installed?"

> The SKU key is nothing but a GUID as you can see in the above table, so we can easily retrieve this information using the below code, use a visual webpart and add this Render method in your UserControl.ascx.cs file.

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        base.Render(writer);


        const string SHAREPOINT2010FOUNDATION = “BEED1F75-C398-4447-AEF1-E66E1F0DF91E”;
        const string SHAREPOINT2010STANDARD = “3FDFBCC8-B3E4-4482-91FA-122C6432805C”;
        const string SHAREPOINT2010ENTERPRISE = “D5595F62-449B-4061-B0B2-0CBAD410BB51″;

        SPFarm _spFarm = SPFarm.Local;


        IEnumerable<Guid> _guid = _spFarm.Products;
        foreach (var item in _guid)
        {

            string _skuID = item.ToString();
            writer.Write(“<div>\n”);
            if (_skuID.Equals(SHAREPOINT2010STANDARD, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                writer.Write(“<span>” + _skuID + ” – You have SharePoint 2010 Standard Edition” + “</span>\n”);
            }
            if (_skuID.Equals(SHAREPOINT2010ENTERPRISE,StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                writer.Write(“<span>” + _skuID + ” – You have SharePoint 2010 Enterprise Edition” + “</span>\n”);
            }
            if (_skuID.Equals(SHAREPOINT2010FOUNDATION, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                writer.Write(“<span>” + _skuID + ” – You have SharePoint 2010 Foundation” + “</span>\n”);
            }

            writer.Write(“</div>\n”);

        }
    }
```

Comment: @j0k turned this into a halfway decent answer by copying in an *actual answer*, instead of it being just a link to your blog. But you have failed to disclose that it is your own blog (which is made apparent by how quickly after a blog post has been made that you have linked to it here in other answers), so I am removing the link to your website.

Comment: @AndrewBarber I think you pinged me but you wanted to ping the answer author, right?

Comment: @j0k I just typed the @ out of habit with your name. Oops! it's his post, so he was notified, too.